# guardar consulta php y mysql

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta que me recibe un "POST" donde viene una variable "nombre" y dos arreglos el primero se llama "dato1" y el segundo "dato2", pero tengo dos inconvenientes el primero es que solo me esta guardando la variable "nombre" y el segundo inconveniente es que si por ejemplo el arreglo viene con tres variables ya que es dinamico me aparece el registro de nombre creado tres veces como si fuera tres registros.

estos son los datos que se envian:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en consola esta es la data que se envia al POST donde tengo el problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**1. Necesito que me guarde los arreglos también en la base de datos**

aparte que se triplica al guardar los registros como si fueran todos diferentes no queda registrado los arreglos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como quiero que quede:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2. que cada vez que guarde en la base de datos que se guarde todo en un único registro**

error cuando guarda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como quiero que quede que no se repita.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
        unset($_POST['METHOD']);
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
foreach ($data as $row) {
   /* $dato1=$row['dato1'];
      $dato2=$row['dato2'];*/
   $query="insert into ingresos2(nombre,dato1,dato2) values ('$nombre','$dato1[$row]','$dato2[$row]')";
        $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos2";
        $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
        echo json_encode($resultado);
  
}
       
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        exit();
    }

header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. *1. Necesito que me guarde los arreglos también en la base de datos* ¿De qué forma, como una lista separada por comas? Muestra un ejemplo de tus datos, para tales fines puedes poner un  `var_dump($_POST);` en tu código y agregas esa salida a la pregunta y pon un ejemplo de cómo tendrían que quedar insertados esos datos en la tabla: *quiero que ESTOS datos queden insertados en una sola fila de ESTE modo* y nos enseñas un ejemplo de la fila que quieres.

Comment: listo, ya agregue mas descripción de lo que no he podido resolver

Comment: A ver la explicación es confusa, aún con capturas de pantalla. Ni siquiera es necesario eso, con que pongas un ejemplo de fila, escrito a mano, bastaría. Quiero que la fila quede así ... y pones el texto de cómo quieres que quede la fila. En tu explicación lo que pareces querer es una fila con `nombre1` y varias sub-filas ¿? En una tabla eso es imposible. Es más, lo propio para este tipo de casos es tener una tercera tabla asociativa donde relaciones por un ID los datos.

Comment: si podria ser tener una segunda tabla para guardar las subfilas, pero como quedaria con mi codigo ?

Comment: Supongamos que esa tabla se llamaría `ingresos_datos`, y que tendría dos columnas: `id_ingreso, dato`, tú orientarías el INSERT hacia esa tabla, algo como: `INSERT INTO ingresos_datos (id_ingreso,dato) VALUES (31,1), (31,2)` es decir, el ingreso `31` tendría asociados en ese contexto dos datos, el dato `1` y el dato `2`   y no tendrías que preocuparte de insertar **datos redundantes** en tu tabla `ingresos`  que es lo que parecería intentas ahora. Ten en cuenta que las bases de datos son relacionales, y esa característica existe, para, entre otras cosas, evitar redundancia en los datos.

Comment: Pero cómo quedaría en código la verdad no he podido hacer que funcione